# How to find null space of a matrix over $\mathbb{GF}(2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, matlab, maple

How to find null space of a matrix over $\mathbb{GF}(2)$ ?

Are there any algorithms available?

I am not sure here is appropriate to ask this or not: Is there any routines for MATLAB or Maple?

Comment: SageMath with Python is one of the most efficient tools for this. It has a lot of math libraries. It can work on finite fields upto sizes $2^k$ where $k\leq 100$ (I think).

Comment: What's wrong with the usual method of reducing your matrix to its reduced row echelon form, and finding the null spaces from there just like in your linear algebra course?

Comment: Dimensions are high enough that working out them is prohibitive.

Comment: Ok. Then you probably need help from someone who is an expert in Maple or Matlab. Out of curiosity. This woudn't be about a long error-correcting code by any chance?

Comment: Just to be clear: you have a binary matrix that you can store, but which is too large to do Gaussian elimination with? I think that means you cannot do matrix multiplication either, and probably that finding the kernel won't be possible either.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: A sparse matrix can be represented by a list of triples (i,j,value) (without the value in this case since it'd always be 1.

Comment: I don't know enough about Galois fields to know if this is correct, but in Matlab `mod(null(sym(A)),2)` might work (where `A` is a numeric matrix). The `sym` tells Matlab to use symbolic rational representations of the values when evaluating `mod` and `null`.

Comment: @xavierm02: That is a live possibility. Seen it (in the context of LDPC-codes). But in those cases the null space is not guaranteed to have a basis consisting of sparse vectors. In the coding theory context that was out of necessity. With a more general sparse binary matrix it may or may not be the case. So I think that Marc's point stands.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial in Maple. If $A$ is the Matrix, then use `Nullspace(A) mod 2`.